# Wamp Dreamweaver: Page links send to live site rather than local

Tags: localhost, wamp, dreamweaver

I have wamp and dreamweaver configured to work together locally for multiple sites. Index file loads fine and I see my front page in DW (localhost/mysite/wordpress/. But, when i click on a link to go to another page, i'm sent to my remote, live site instead of staying in localhost. How do I follow links and stay in localhost?

Win Vista Ultimate, Apache 2.4.2, mysql 5.5.24

thnx!
gil

Comment: There is more to copying a live WP site to localhost than meets the eye. Read this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/copying-site-to-localhost

Comment: I have experienced the same frustration of the original poster of that thread, one who, I might add, never did find satisfaction. Like the OP, I have been through all the various config files, from hosts to config to both httpd's 3 times and more. Clicking on any menu link on my index home page in Dreamweaver still takes me to my live, remote site...

Comment: WP hold the site url that you use when you install it in its database. If its just a basic WP install its fairly easy to find and edit the url's and make them local facing, but with every addon there is the possibility that the addon also stores url information so the process get progressively more complex. It is not a DW or WAMPServer issue its WP and the way it works that make this a bit of a pain. But it is fixable

Comment: thnx. when you say find and edit the url's, do you mean in the database somewhere? I've been to the wp_options, where there is only one url,"siteurl", and that seems to be fine:http://localhost/mysite/wordpress  i'm still learning about databases

Comment: well, i mucked it all up pretty good trying to fix. so, re-downloaded entire site, imported its database, pointed urls in wp-options correctly (i guess), everything works, i can see/edit all pages from wordpress admin, the urls of which look like: http://localhost/mycustomtheme/page_whatever/. I can even paste that url into Dreamweaver's address window and see the page via localhost. But, I cannot follow links in dreamweaver's design window without going out to the live site. I guess I should live with it, but I know it's not right... thnx